# Where should Authentication and Authorization belong to?

Tags: .net, spring, authentication, authorization, clean-architecture

In my opinion, Authentication and Authorization should be handle in service or usecase layer, following ddd, those stuffs consider as busiess logics, so it should be handled in service or usecase layer.

But I see a lot of developer (from fresher to experienced dev on youtube) do those things in middleware layer or even controller. and a lot of frameworks like .net or spring support built-in middlewares to do those things very ellw.

What is your experience about this, which way do you think is better?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents are: if authentication/authorization are features/cases of your app, then it should be implemented like any other feature/use cases of your app.

If is desired levaraging runtime/framework code, it should call domain layer / usecase instead of make it all in app layer.